# meaning of yek in Persian or Farsi

Tags: grammar, persian

I know that in Persian "Man yek sag daraam" means "I have a dog", where:
Man = I, sag = dog, daraam = have. What is the purpose of yek? Is it a/an, the indefinite article?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! Questions seeking help with translation and localization are off-topic here. Your question looks like it asks for translation, however the deeper look reveals that `yek` is a numeral "one" that acts similarly to an article. Consider expanding your question so it did not attract possible close-votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "one" (the number) but is also used as an indefinite article, just like (for example) un(e) in French.